# conditional typing issue in typescript + react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am getting below error

**Type '{ error: false; }' is not assignable to type 'x'.
Type '{ error: false; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ErrorWithMessage2': name, message**

I am trying to add conditional tying **error: true** then **errorMessage** is **required**
else **error: false** **errorMessage** is **non mandatory**

```
interface Error {
  error: boolean;
}

interface ErrorWithMessage extends Error {
  error: true;
  errorMessage: string;
}

interface ErrorWithMessage2 extends Error {
  error: false;
  errorMessage?: string;
}

type x = ErrorWithMessage | ErrorWithMessage2;

const abc: x = {
  error: false,
};
```

if you see abc is type **"x"** still giving error why ?

Comment: I've tried it with TS v5.3.2 and everything works well, which TS are you using? If at least 4.8 you can try next `const abc = {
  error: false,
} satisfies x;`

Answer (score 1):

`Error` is already a globally defined interface, so when you do this:

```
interface Error {
  error: boolean;
}
```

Your interface gets [merged](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) with the global definition. As a result, `Error`s must have not just an `error` property, but also a `name`, `message`, and optionally a `stack`.

To fix this use a different name, such as:

```
interface MyError {
  error: boolean;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CiUoHsrIDeAUMstHlAFzIBGuuANhHCANzEC%20xxoksiFNkoB1YGAAWqCAGcZcAOYoIAD0ggAJjLRYc%20IqXJ7qyMFACuEDmQr5pcxRBoyzoBR269w0eEmTD8MUl7eSUAJnI1CE1tDACCEhtjGnhGGStDWygQxwB%20Z1cQdy4eMHQABxQVZABef2MgqVlQlAAfetFxJodwjmIEXBAXZDhaBBpqusSjShS4NIgAGi42MmQgA)